# Credentials are "Incorrect" When Logging in to Postfix Mail Server

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

Recently I wanted to play around with mail servers, so I followed the steps in [this](http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-centos-7/) article. But when I tried logging in with Mozilla Thunderbird, it gave me this error:

[Configuration could not be verified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdGnT.png)

I tried different accounts and changing passwords, but it hasn't been working. What is going on here?

Also, does anyone know of any mail servers better than this one?

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks

**EDIT:**

There was a typo in this file:

```
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
```

There is this line here:

```
mail_location = maildir:/path/to/mail/
```

Which I forgot to include `maildir:` before the path.

Comment: This could be one of 10,000 things. We need more information. Can you provide an excerpt of your mail.log when you try to connect with thunderbird? If you see no indication of any connection attempt in the log, it's probably a DNS issue, in which case we'd need your domain to look at the DNS records...

Comment: @JoeBrailsford Yes, sure. I was hoping someone would say this because I don't even know what to provide! May I ask where the log is? Also, it was able to automatically fetch the configuration.

Comment: I don't use CentOS, but google tells me you could find mail related logs under /var/logs/maillog. Do a `tail -f /var/log/maillog` and try to connect with Thunderbird, stick the output in your question.

Comment: @JoeBrailsford Okay, sure!

Comment: did you find your mail log file?

Comment: @JoeBrailsford Oh, sorry forgot about that. I'm logged in, but there are more problems now. There was a typo in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf

Comment: Well, put your problems in the question, we'll work through them.

Comment: @JoeBrailsford Actually, everything is working fine now. Thanks very much!

Comment: Excellent, no problem. As an FYI, I'd advise you look at opendkim, opendmarc, amavis/spamassassin and beyond that, security best practices around your firewall, mitigation of brute force (ssh and mailbox) and intrusion detection - if you're planning to use this for more than just a tinker.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in this file:

`/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`

There is this line here:

`mail_location = maildir:/path/to/mail/`

Which I forgot to include `maildir:` before the path.

Thanks to Joe Brailsford for telling me to check the log.